# Parse list 3 threads a time, when 5 completed works, server signal to do something

Tags: pthreads, mutex, semaphore

Hy I am curious does anyone know a tutorial example where semaphores are used for more than 1 process /thread. I'm looking forward to fix this problem. I have an array, of elements and an x number of threads. This threads work over the array, only 3 at a moment. After 5 works have been completed, the server is signelised and it clean those 5 nodes. But I'm having problems with the designing this problem. (node contains worker value which contains the 'name' of the thread that is allowed to work on it, respectivly nrNodes % nrThreads)
In order to make changes on the list a mutex is neccesarly in order not to overwrite / make false evaluations.

But i have no clue how to limit 3 threads to parse, at a given point, the list, and how to signal the main for cleaning session. I have been thinking aboutusing a semafor and a global constant. When the costant reaches 5, the server to be signaled(which probably would eb another thread.)

Sorry for lack of code but this is a conceptual question, what i have written so far doesn't affect the question in any way.

Comment: Semaphores are supposed to be used by multiple threads, all examples and tutorials should show how they are used by _at least_ two threads. The actual number of threads waiting on a semaphore or mutex doesn't really matter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg so can I definea semaphore to signal when a global variable has reached a value?

Comment: Well, you use semaphores (or mutexes) to protect common resources, and monitors (or condition variables) to signal events.

Comment: ty, i think i got it, any idea how to fix the other problem?